# Add Athelas Font

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to set a custom font onto LaTex? I'm trying to use [Athelas](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/athelas) font but I can't seem to find a way? I've downloaded ttf file for the font? The tutorials online have dead links or aren't too digestible for a beginner like me. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to use it just for a few lines, or as the main font for a whole document?

Comment: Whole document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the font to your computer, then use `\usepackage{fontspec}` and  `\setmainfont{Athelas}` in the preamble of the document, and be sure to compile the document with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.  Just make sure the name you use in the argument of `\setmainfont` matches the name of the font as it appears in your Fonts directory.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to mention the need to load the `fontspec` package and to compile the document with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I went in to edit a typo after your edit, not knowing that would delete your edit credit.

Comment: Do I have to use XeLaTeX or LulaLaTeX? I rather not install another compiler.

Comment: @KevinM - You ask, "Do I have to use XeLaTeX or LulaLaTeX?" Short answer: Yes. Longer Answer: Absolutely. Good news: Unless your TeX installation is positively ancient, both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX should be installed by default.

Comment: It unfortunately appears so. Error message:
fontspec error: "Cannot-use-pdftxt"
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX

Comment: @KevinM - What the error message you report demonstrates is merely that you were trying to compile a document that loads the `fontspec` package under pdfLaTeX. That's most definitelty *not* going to work. As was noted in the answer, you *must* switch the compiler to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.